# NodeJS & Redis null responses

Tags: node.js, redis

I am working on a NodeJS app that runs fine on a Redis database that it creates.

There is an older version of the same application that uses a database with slightly less info in it.

My goal is to use my new app with the old database by introducing error handling for queries that may be invalid.

When I switch my dev app to a copy of the older database I get the below error:

```
/root/z-nomp/node_modules/redis/lib/utils.js:7
    if (reply.length === 0 || !(reply instanceof Array)) {
              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.replyToObject [as reply_to_object] (/root/z-nomp/node_modules/redis/lib/utils.js:7:15)
    at RedisClient.handle_reply (/root/z-nomp/node_modules/redis/index.js:314:23)
    at multi_callback (/root/z-nomp/node_modules/redis/lib/multi.js:79:43)
    at Command.callback (/root/z-nomp/node_modules/redis/lib/multi.js:116:9)
    at normal_reply (/root/z-nomp/node_modules/redis/index.js:721:21)
    at RedisClient.return_reply (/root/z-nomp/node_modules/redis/index.js:819:9)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.returnReply (/root/z-nomp/node_modules/redis/index.js:192:18)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.execute (/root/z-nomp/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:574:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/z-nomp/node_modules/redis/index.js:274:27)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:256:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:602:20)
```

The library where this error occurs is here: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/blob/master/lib/utils.js

Do I need to introduce error handling into this module itself?

For what it's worth the code of the original app is here:  https://github.com/zone117x/node-open-mining-portal

And the code that I am forking from is here:  https://github.com/z-classic/z-nomp

Are there some common pitfalls present in this type of situation that I should be aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: I think we'd need to see YOUR code that calls into this library or causes a call into this library.  The problem is probably with parameters you are passing into some library you are using.

Comment: My code is under the z-nomp link.

I'm not sure exactly where it's being called as the stack trace seems to start on a TCP read.

Comment: Well, in order to entice someone to help you, you probably need to distill down what code you are doing that leads to this - to at least point us to the right portion of the code rather than just give us links to three large bodies of code.  This is basic debugging.  For example, you might start with the differences between the old and new database and try to develop a theory on why this things missing from the old database might cause a problem and what you could do about that.  Maybe you need to process the old database to add stuff to it to be compatible.

Comment: That's part of my larger problem -- I don't know what calls lead to this.

Maybe I should generalize my question -- part of what I need is to know where to look to take things from here.

Comment: And, you think we would?  When we know nothing about your old database or about this code in general?  This is a debugging problem.  You need to do some debugging to narrow down what might be causing the problem.   We don't have the ability to do that.

Comment: FYI, the comments in that range of the redis code make it sound like it's probably attempting to read some data from the database internally and what it gets back is not what it expects and thus `reply` is `undefined` rather than the object it should normally be.  Perhaps you should process the old database to make it look like the new database (add/modify whatever is different or missing).  Or export the data and insert it into a new database.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a debug answer. As stated in the comments we would need code to be able to make an evaluation.

However based on the error you are getting it is clear that 'reply' is returning as a undefined or null. I will assume you knew that much.

First your code really has to check for things like that. You are jumping straight to length (actually an incredibly bad thing to check reasons would be apparent to anyone who understands difference between undefined, bull, empty strings and an object). However you seem to have no check for reply  and it is returning undefined.

As to your overall node-redis marriage this is very common. And usually a really good idea in many situations. BUT when you use Redis be careful to monitor your throughput and if used with such libraries as Socket.io you face a whole new family of problems to overcome.

All the above was just a quick look as I was on the train. So please excuse spelling mistakes and lack of proper use of bold comment etc.

You really need to evaluate your variables especially when you don't know if they will even hold anything. Promises callbacks async await all are your friends in this case.